# Android - Kotlin : Communication between two calss's

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new with Android Studio and Kotlin. I am building an App that will be capable of Login/Register users with email + password and Login with Google Account.

I get everything working following Google and Youtube tutorials, but all my code was inside my Activity.
My goal is to get all the code in different class's.

For example when the user is logging in with user + password, I pass the email and password to a methode inside another class, let name it simplesLogin.

Inside simpleLogin I will do all the code working with Firebase so verify if the email and password are valid (or not) and return the result to the Activity.

The problem is there is "addOnCompleteListener" and "startActivityForResult" that will not allow to return from a method directly.

In the end my big question is: What is the proper way to communicate between two class's and/or between a class and Activity?

I used to program C++ in Qt Framework and I am used to implement the concept of Signals/Slots. There is anything similar in Kotlin?

I search on Google and found Interface implementation examples as communication between two fragments but I am not being able to implement those examples to my case. Specially with the "startActivityForResult" needs.

What would be the best way to get all the code on different class's and do a proper communication to the main Activity?

Comment: To communicate with an Activity you can pass data on the Intent used to start it. Note that the standard way to do UI is now using Fragments, not Activities. You might consider checking the Navigation Jetpack.

Comment: @m0skit0 but I dont want to start another Activity with a UI... I want to process the login on a different class in background and the notified by the results,. I know I can have a Activity with no UI, and I can putExtra on starting and returning to/from Activities, but that is the best way? What happens when from my MainAtivity I start another activity with no UI (no layout) ? I am confused with some concepts...

Comment: I didn't mean to have an Activity without a UI. Have you looked into different view architectures, like MVP or MVVM? Those solve exactly your problem.